# Steepest Descent Algorithm for Solving Linear Systems

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I am trying to implement the steepest descent algorithm for linear systems. The equation is below:

$\begin{align*}
Ax &= b\\
x_0 &= [0]*[m,n]\\
x_k &= x_{k-1} + \frac{|d_{k-1}|^2}{d_{k-1} * Ad_{k-1}}d_{k-1}\\
d_{k-1} &= -(Ax_{k-1} - b)
\end{align*}$

My problem is that I think $d_{k-1}$ should be an $m\times1$ matrix and when you try and dot the denominator of $x_k$ it does not work because you end up trying to dot an $m\times1$ by an $m\times1$ matrix.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have written as "$d_{k-1} * Ad_{k-1}$" is more properly written as $$\color{red}{d_{k-1}^\top}\color{blue}A\color{magenta}{d_{k-1}}$$

that is; a quadratic form. You are taking the product of $\color{red}{1\times m}$, $\color{blue}{m\times m}$, and $\color{magenta}{m\times 1}$ matrices, and you wind up with a scalar result as it should be, since it's in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what I was missing.